MySQL redo log error (log files come from different directory)
I've set up a PHP + MySQL project on a client's computer. Now, they're facing a problem. This is the second time I've fixed it. The MySQL80 process stops working. If I manually try to start it from Windows Services, it shows
"The MySQL service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs."
Upon investigating the error logs, this is what I've found:

2024-09-08T05:56:04.367317Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.39) MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-09-08T08:00:51.288588Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.39) starting as process 3784
2024-09-08T08:00:51.319398Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-09-08T08:00:51.443771Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013879] [InnoDB] The redo log file .#innodb_redo#ib_redo54 comes from other data directory than redo log file .#innodb_redo#ib_redo2.
2024-09-08T08:00:51.444941Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2024-09-08T08:00:51.466675Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2024-09-08T08:00:51.468117Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2024-09-08T08:00:51.468786Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-09-08T08:00:51.469578Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.39) MySQL Community Server - GPL.

I went into the #innodb_redo folder. There were two log files named #ib_redo54 and #ib_redo2. After I deleted them, mysql80 service started successfully and the project is also running well. Also, there were many other #ib_redoN_tmp files generated there.
So the solution seems simple. But doing it every few days seems problematic. What's the reason behind this problem? And is there a permanent solution to this?

You need to check the error.log in the MySQL folder and see what problem MySQL faces, if you problem post the content
